# Knob Identification

Tags: valve, heat

Background: I just moved into a new apartment. The apartment has a heating system unlike my last one. I need help determining the purpose of this knob above one of the radiators along the wall. The knob says "Open".

This is a New York City apartment.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! [image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel New York City!

Comment: Appears more likely to be something associated with the window that it's apparently on the sill of as opposed to the radiator that's not even in the picture. Half of a child-proofing lock or something like that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Oh, that's interesting, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: why don't you move the handle in the direction of "open"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That has nothing to do with your heating system.

That is an old telephone jack box.  If you move that cover in the Open direction, you should see it uncover a 4 wire telephone jack.  The slot is to allow the wire to come out while you close it back.

Here is one photo of a new one... I'll look for something better [telephone jack](https://todayshomeowner.com/how-to-install-a-phone-jack/)